# Alter Table too slow in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter-table

I'm trying to add a new column

```
ALTER TABLE "Cidade" ADD COLUMN "BoundBox" VARCHAR(255)
```

to this table:

```
 "Cidade"
    "Id" integer not null
        constraint "Cidade_PK"
            primary key,
    "Nome" varchar(120),
    "EstadoId" integer not null
        constraint "Estado_Cidade_FK"
            references "Estado",
    "PontoCentralLatitude" numeric,
    "PontoCentralLongitude" numeric
```

But the query never finish, I've already waited for 5 minutes and nothing happened. The table has only 5,000 records, and I can't wait too much time since it block the access to the table.
I have a test database (equal to production), and it worked very quickly.
The postgres version is 9.5.6.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you are running PostgreSQL 9.6+ you can use `pg_blocking_pids()` to find PID of queries that lock your one.

```
select pid, pg_blocking_pids(pid) as blocked_by, query as blocked_query
from pg_stat_activity
where pg_blocking_pids(pid)::text != '{}';
```

Answer (score 10):

This statement is very fast, but it needs an access exclusive lock on the table. There must be a long running transaction that holds a lock on the table and block you.

Use the `pg_stat_activity` view to find the long transaction.

Answer (score 5):

If nothing blocks your query and query executing very long time and this table has many DELETE queries try to clean your table:

```
VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) table_name;
```

Comment: Indexes may be a cause here as well. Appreciate the note.

Answer (score 3):

As per your description it seems this table is highly used in system and your alter statement is taking time to acquire a lock on table to do the job. Try to find a window where you get less load on system and run .